# find the second derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the following:
$$
-2\frac{\partial^2 Y_0}{\partial x\,\partial\zeta}-\frac{\partial Y_0}{\partial x}-xY_0
$$
given:
$$
Y_0=A_0 (x)+B_0 (x)e^{-\zeta}
$$

Comment: If you intended to write partial derivatives, use $\partial$      ("\partial") instead of $\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial Y_0}{\partial x} = A_0'(x)+B_0'(x)e^{-\zeta}$,

then $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 Y_0}{\partial x\partial\zeta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\zeta}\frac{\partial Y_0}{\partial x} = -B_0'(x)e^{-\zeta}$.